# Undo path that leads to $20 DLC purchase on Fire Emblem Fates

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

My cousin received Fire Emblem Fates as a present last week. He started playing it and got a few chapters/levels in when it asks him to pick a side. He chose one and completed the next level, but now it's asking him to pay $20 to continue.

Can he go back to select the free path without restarting his save file? Money is very tight for both of our families so we can't afford the $20 DLC, and he can't go back to pick the other side without restarting the whole game.

Comment: Fire Emblem Fates comes in 2 versions, each version comes with it's own side and the other side has to be brought as DLC. there is also a third side which both games need to buy

Comment: @Memor-X I'm aware that they have their own free side. What I'm asking is if he is able to go back to pick the other side without restarting all of his progress. When he loads his save file, it immediately asks him to pay for the path. No option to go back to the path selection

Comment: You're basically asking for help with pirating the content, which isn't something we can help with, regardless of how abhorrent or not you believe it to be.

Comment: @Ash I understood that shortly after, I edited the post to better reflect what I'm asking

Comment: @kkirigaya you're still asking to bypass the paywall. We're not going to help with that. Whether or not there is a legit way to go back is another, separate question.

Comment: @kkirigaya no because the games have the initial programming to show all the choices but only the code for one choice, the other 2 have to be brought and downloaded. i understand that when you complete the game you can restart the game and make a separate choice but i have not played it myself to know all the details of if this is a New Game Plus which carries over data from your previous play through or not

Comment: I've edited your question to narrow it down to what seems to be your core request. If this isn't correct, you can revert the changes with the [Edit] link.

Comment: The game is rather clear about what is and isn't DLC when choosing your path.  Choosing a paid path at that point is made with full knowledge, I believe.

Comment: @Frank Technically correct, but not everyone carefully reads and comprehends what a game tells them, particularly in the case of children. Accidentally selecting the wrong option is not unbelievable.

Comment: @Michaellogg No, not unbelievable; I never said that.  But it's pretty rough to want to play a path that's unpaid.  We can help direct you to an option that's legitimate, but asking for us to help bypass the paywall?  Yeah, no, that's not kosher.

Answer (score 7):

### Select "Branch of Fate" on the main menu

The "Branch of Fate" option allows you to start a new save file immediately before the choice of which path to take. You're able to change the details of your avatar character, but it automatically fills in most of the previous details for you. Simply select the path for the game you actually have, and you're good to go.

Even though it's technically a new save file, you're started in the same state as you were in when you first reached the path option, making it effectively a rollback.

Comment: Is this the only option, forcing him to restart his save file? There's no way he can revert back to before he chose the path? Maybe in the SD card data or something?

Comment: @kkirigaya I doubt it, and again, that's getting into breaking copy protections and editing the game which likely breaks a few EULA type agreements. If the game doesn't allow for it organically, that's unfortunately the way it is.

Comment: @kkirigaya It's not restarting the save file any more than reverting back to that chapter would be. You're placed in a state identical to when you last reached that point in the game.

Comment: To clarify: he'll lose only one level's worth of progress by going back to the choice via a "branch of fate". This game splits after that choice so any progress made on pne route isn't relevant to the others. This answer is correct, so could you mark it as accepted so Michaellogg can get the credit.